# How to include remote Addressables group in the application build, to always have cached version

Tags: unity-game-engine, assets, addressables

I have the remote assets group in my Addressables settings. It is pretty large, changes rarely and should be downloaded for proper application work. So that, I want to keep this group in build, but still checking its remote updates. I want to do it, to not wait long downloading on the first apllication start.

Is there a way to include remote assets group in build, but still continue handle it as a remote group, that can be updated?